# Need help identifying Li-ion battery pin order on pager

Tags: batteries, identification, pins

I have several PERCOMM E80 pagers that are missing batteries. Usually I use my test battery with clamps on + and - to power up various electronics and it works like a charm. But not on this one. There is very little information on it online other than the FCC documentation. There are 4 pins that connect to a battery so maybe the device needs to be connected to the BT and BSI pins to power on, but I can't figure out the order. I've tried the - and + clamps in every combination possible but no luck. All I know that if I connect them to the middle ones, the battery shorts. I know the original battery was 3.6V and mine is also so no problems there.
Please click on the photo below to see the PCB. I can provide a better close-up later, if it help.

Photo:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the PCB traces, I would guess there is two groups of 2 pins but probably no indication of polarity. You can also get the service manual, that would be the best solution.

Comment: It would help but no documentation is available. I'll try giving power to the charging port and get the multimeter to the battery pins at least try to find the - and +

Comment: It would be great if you can borrow a working unit.

Answer (score 0):

I've got one working and in service right now (and several I'd like to have working), and the original battery isn't holding much of a charge, so it would seem we're in similar straits. I was thinking about either having someone fab packs to the original specifications or retrofitting some prismatic cells into the cavity.

I don't remember the pinouts, but I will put a voltmeter on mine and see what I find. Also, if you happen to know which revision of the e80 you have, it might help.

Comment: You realize this was posted in March yeah? There's an unhelpful feature of this site "bumping" old posts to the top of the main page. I wouldn't spend any time on this unless the OP is still responsive.